# How to force a recheck on purchasable apps on USC?

Tags: software-center

I've been trying to install some games via the USC, but they keep on saying they are not compatible with my Ubuntu version. However, when I check online, for example here:

- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fieldrunners/

It says that 12.10 is available. However, when I open USC, it refuses to install it, stating that it's "not available for this Ubuntu version".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a problem with FieldRunners that is now fixed. I believe it should install correctly this time.

The problem is that FieldRunners was 32 bit only so if you were running 64 bit, it would give you that error even though it was visible. If this is not the case, please let us know. The best route is through pay-support at canonical.com

Comment: Ah, thank you. Yes, I am running 64-bit, so that explains it. However, I believe the fact there's no way to recheck might be a serparate issue. If I may ask, when is Osmos/Shatter coming?